# Evolution of quantum state that cannot exist with accompanying Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-evolution

So I am studying a certain Hamiltonian that has projection operators in its definition. To keep it simple, suppose our Hilbert space is a one particle system that can be spin up/spin down (excited, non excited state), with Hamiltonian  H = ZP , with P projector on non excited state and Z the pauli spin matrix, which just measures the spin in the z-direction.

Now we know that the excited state is not allowed because $H |\uparrow > = 0$ because of the projection operator in the Hamiltonian. But if we do prepare our system in that state and look at the time evolution for a small time interval $\Delta t$:

$ \exp(-iH(\Delta t) | \uparrow >  = \textbf{1} |\uparrow> -  i\Delta t \cdot H |\uparrow> = |\uparrow>$

and so time evolution just leaves the excited state in the excited state, but I would suspect it should "annihilate" it? Why isn't this so?

Answer (score 1):

If $H= \sigma_z P$, where 
$$
P= \left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0&1}\right]
$$ 
is the projector on spin down, 
then
$$
H= \left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0 &-1}\right]\left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0&1}\right]= \left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0 &-1}\right].
$$
so the two eigenstates are $(1,0)^T$ with energy zero and $(0,1)^T$ with energy $-1$ and
$$
\exp\{-iHt/\hbar\}= \left[\matrix{0&0\cr 0 &e^{it/\hbar}}\right].
$$

Under time evolution $(1,0)^T\to (1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T\to e^{it/\hbar} (0,1)^T$.  What is  confusing here?

By the way, (Grammar Police warning!) why start your question with the word "So"? Why not simply say  "I am studying..."  Starting with "So" seems so unnecessary...

Comment: Well in my specific case the projection operator is meant to project out these states because they cannot exist. I am actually looking at a many-body problem here and it's an array of spin sites, in which neighboring spins cannot be both in the excited state (Rydberg blockade). I just find it strange that if would start with a state that has certain overlaps with these "forbidden" states, they remain in this state forever as they are not projected out in time evolution or anything. They just remain "static" as E=0 indeed.

Comment: As for the starting with the "So", I'm not a native speaker and I tend to do that a lot, because it's common in my language to start off with that same word ;)

Comment: @CFRedDemon. Ah!  thanks for the remark about "So". I see it a lot and wondered where it came from. It's not a good idea to use it in formal english. It looks odd, but does not affect  the  understandablity.   I also see what you mean about "forbidden"  The states are still in the Hilbert space, but they are isolated from all others. They must not be killed by time evolution however, or that would  lose the state normalization.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get them out of the Hilbert space then? Or it probably is just wrong to start off with a certain state then, because it is physically impossible? Then again, if you have this Hamiltonian in real life it would not be hard to set up your system in a forbidden state as a free system and then "turn on" this Hamiltonian. This then just freezes the dynamics of the forbidden states. Interesting stuff. Also thanks for the remark on the 'So', I will remember that for when I write my thesis later this year.